# Changing a boolean in a variable from Identifiable struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct Item: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id = UUID()
    var image: String
    var name: String
    var price: Int
    var isFavorite: Bool
}

class Model: ObservableObject{
    @Published var group = [Item]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(group){
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "peopleKey")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    init(){
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "peopleKey"),
           let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: savedItems) {
            group = decodedItems
        } else {
            group = itemData
        }
    }
    
    var itemData: [Item] = [
        Item(image: "imageGIFT", name: "Flower",price: 5 , isFavorite: false),
        Item(image: "imageGIFT", name: "Coffe Cup",price: 9 , isFavorite: false),
        Item(image: "imageGIFT", name: "Teddy Bear",price: 2 , isFavorite: false),
        Item(image: "imageGIFT", name: "Parfume",price: 8 , isFavorite: false)
    ]
    
}
```

I am trying to change variables on this struct and I define as var but after encode and decode they has been let. I changed let part to var then Xcode gived an error.

Comment: `first` is constant you can update like this `peopleData[0].myPeople.toggle()` but this will make app crash if your array is empty

Comment: Its not give an error but not work too. Nothing is chance when I press button. Should I do Observable this array ?

Comment: If you are listing to change in `SwiftUI` then yes it should be either `@State` or `@Published` property

Comment: My arrays @Published but I edit the question can you check again ? Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Add code where you are using this array in `SwiftUI` and also add code where you trying to update toggle bool which is not working for you

Comment: I edit my question again and add view part too just I can't understand the way of work this arrays. I add a new array to view part but that's not work too.

Comment: `I checked documentations too but I understand nothing`, that is your main problem here.
Read the very basics of Swift first, especially regarding arrays, here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html
 then do what everyone does, small steps to learn the language, then progress to tutorials etc...
 Without knowing the basics you will keep struggling to deal with very simple code.

Comment: thank you for advice i will do but the part i didnt understand, in Person struct i can change name, age or jub strings and Ints but when its come to bool its not working thats feel kind of bug. I am working on swift UI for 3 months and still those little problems can be disgusting. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: `..when its come to bool its not working ...`,
where in your code do you change the `bool` value, presumably of `var myPerson: Bool`?

Comment: model.people[0].name = "Franz"    when I write this in my button and click that its work fine and change name to Franz, but model.people[0].myPerson.toggle() is not working. I change manually for see is that really change and its work when I did manually, but not work on button. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: show the code in your question, so we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I edit the question. After some changes same problem but I have no idea how to fix. I changed let parts to the var but then x code gived me an error and its not work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine and I can change spesific part. like model.group[0].isFavorite.Toggle is work but Item.isFavorite.Toggle not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my test code that shows doing `model.people[0].myPerson.toggle()` in the `Button`
does work. I have made some minor mods and added some comments to the code.

I suggest again, read the **very basics of Swift**,
in particular the array section at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html.
Without understanding these very basic concepts you will keep struggling to code your App.

Note, there is probably no need for the `myPeople` array in your `Model`, but if that's what you want to have.

```
struct Person: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var job: String
    var myPerson: Bool
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: [Person] = []
    @Published var myPeople: [Person] = []
    
    init(){
        addPeople()
    }

    // completely useless
    func addPeople(){
        people = peopleData
        myPeople = peopleData.filter { $0.myPerson }
    }
    
    // here inside the class and using `Person` not `person`
    var peopleData = [
        Person(name: "Bob", age: 22, job: "Student", myPerson: false),
        Person(name: "John", age: 26, job: "Chef", myPerson: false)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            VStack {
                // this `myPeople` array is empty at first, nothing is displayed
                ForEach(model.myPeople) { person in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(person.name)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Age: \(person.age)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Job: \(person.job)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("myPerson: " + String(person.myPerson)).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            VStack {
                // this `people` array has two items in it
                ForEach(model.people) { person in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(person.name)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("Age: \(person.age)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("Job: \(person.job)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("myPerson: " + String(person.myPerson)).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            Button("Click") {
                print("\n--> before name: \(model.people[0].name) ")
                print("--> before myPerson: \(model.people[0].myPerson) ")
                model.people[0].name = "Franz"
                model.people[0].myPerson.toggle()
                print("\n--> after name: \(model.people[0].name) ")
                print("--> after myPerson: \(model.people[0].myPerson) ")

                // update the myPeople array (the blue items)
                model.myPeople = model.people.filter { $0.myPerson }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use this code using only one array of `people: [Person]`:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: [Person] = []

    init(){
        addPeople()
    }

    func addPeople() {
        people = peopleData
    }
    
    // here inside the class and using `Person` not `person`
    var peopleData = [
        Person(name: "Bob", age: 22, job: "Student", myPerson: false),
        Person(name: "John", age: 26, job: "Chef", myPerson: false)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                // here filter on myPerson=true
                ForEach(model.people.filter { $0.myPerson }) { person in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(person.name)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Age: \(person.age)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("Job: \(person.job)").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        Text("myPerson: " + String(person.myPerson)).foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            VStack {
                // here filter on myPerson=false
                ForEach(model.people.filter { !$0.myPerson }) { person in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Name: \(person.name)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("Age: \(person.age)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("Job: \(person.job)").foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("myPerson: " + String(person.myPerson)).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            Button("Click") {
                model.people[0].name = "Franz"
                model.people[0].myPerson.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I started to read the swift book. I hope will learn important details. Thank you again.